# Properties of functions of mean zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Let $f,g: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable functions and $a<b$ such that
$$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\;dx=0 \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\;dx=0 \tag{1}.$$

So, I think that I can conclude that
$$\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)\;dx=0 \tag{2}$$

Moreover, I can conclude that
$$\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)\;dx=0 \Rightarrow f(b)-f(a)=0? \tag{3}$$
And
$$g(b)\cdot f'(b)-g(a)\cdot f'(a)=0? \tag{4}$$

I ask this because I would like to conclude that
$$g(x)\cdot f'(x)\Bigg|_{a}^{b} -\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)g'(x)\;dx=-\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)g'(x)\;dx. \tag{5}$$

These statements are in general true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding (1) and (2) observe
$$\frac 12 \int_{-1}^1 x \, dx = 0$$
yet
$$ \int_{-1}^1 1\, dx = 2.$$

Comment: And if $f'$ is non constant?

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno How about $f(x) = x^3$ then?

Comment: In my case, $f'$ and $g'$ are non constants. And my main interest are the equation (5). That is, in some sense (or under adittional hypothesis) (5) is true?

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno It doesn't hold in general. Take ${f(x) = x^3, g(x) = x^3,a=-1,b=1}$. Then ${g(x)f'(x)|_{-1}^{1}=3x^5|_{-1}^{1}=6\neq 0}$

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos x \text{ d}x =0$$

and
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin x \text{ d}x =2$$